# How can I avoid to reload page in "menu dropdown" HTML with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">Sort by</span>
        <span class="visible-xs-inline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="newest_to_oldest" data-sort="newest_to_oldest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Newest to Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="oldest_to_newest" data-sort="oldest_to_newest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Oldest to Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="most_posts" data-sort="most_posts"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Most posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="zero" data-sort="zero"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Post senza risposta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

I need to detect when I click on the this element:

```
<li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

The problem is (I think) that when I click on the element the page is reloaded so I can't do my operation when I click on the element. I need that when I click on the element I can do my operation e after reload the page but I don't know if it is possible.My wrong jquery code is:

```
$('a[data-sort]').click(function() {
  console.log("CLICK DAT SORT");
  if ($(this).is('[data-sort="most_views"]')) {
    // do my operation

  }
});
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prevent the defeult behaviour (for the a element, is to open the link)

```
$('a[data-sort]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  ...
```

The .click function passes the event to the handler, and the event can be stopped: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to follow your  link use return false;

It will modify the browser default behaviour and your page will not be reloaded.

```
$('a[data-sort]').click(function() {
     console.log("CLICK DAT SORT");
     if ($(this).is('[data-sort="most_views"]')) {
         // do my operation

         }

         return false;
});
```